# how to refer images in javascript file which are located in different folder?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have below folders in my web application.

inside

```
       webapp/public/images/some.png
       webapp/public/js/somejs.js

       webapp/WEB-INF/some.jsp
```

Now inside `somejs.js` i need to refer `some.png` and am refering as below but it is not picking the image. do i need to change the url?

My jsp file is located in `WEB-INF` folder

```
$('#myform #someId').html('<img src="../images/some.png" /> <span style="color:green">Successfully Saved</span>');
```

Comment: The path to the image is relative to the path of the document loaded, not to the path of the script loaded by the document.

Comment: hi , this will depand on where html page exist and your image reference work from there not from js file

Comment: In most case, you can simply use `/images/some.png` assuming `webapp/public` is your document root.

Comment: Did you try images/some.png instead?

Comment: My jsp file is located in WEB-INF folder..

Comment: You could use a full URL to the image file if there are problems with relative paths for some reason. like ... `http://mydomain/images/some.png` , although relative to the root as in techfoobar's comment looks fine

Comment: @Dom, Thanks for your reply. here i cannot hard code mydomain as it keeps changing. Thanks!

Comment: ah. well, `document.location.hostname` could do it then, for your prefix

Comment: could you please have some snippet here? so that i can understand how to refer document.location.hostname  ? Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your directory structure, the path of the png relative to the jsp would be `../public/images/some.png`, or, assuming that `webapp` is in the root of your domain, `/webapp/public/images/some.png`